# How to use scrollTo in locomotive-scroll with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, locomotive-scroll

How to configure the LocomotiveScrollProvider so that when the button is pressed, it scrolls to the top of page?

```
<LocomotiveScrollProvider
  options={
    {
      smooth: true,
   
    }
  }
  watch={
    []
  }
  onLocationChange={scroll => scroll.scrollTo(0, { duration: 0, disableLerp: true })}
  onUpdate={() => console.log('Updated, but not on location change!')} 
>

<button onClick = {}> Click </button>

</LocomotiveScrollProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location `location={asPath}` in the LocomotiveScrollProvider. So your code will be :

```
const { asPath } = useRouter(); // With next/router
    
<LocomotiveScrollProvider
      options={
    {
      smooth: true,
   
    }
  }
  watch={
    [asPath]
  }
  location={asPath}
  onLocationChange={scroll => scroll.scrollTo(0, { duration: 0, disableLerp: true })}
  onUpdate={() => console.log('Updated, but not on location change!')} 
>

<button onClick = {}> Click </button>

</LocomotiveScrollProvider>
```

See full documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-locomotive-scroll)